# When are azaleas blooming in Sendai?

Tags: japan, weather-and-climate, seasonal, tohoku, vegetation

[Sendai](https://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Sendai) ([North Japan](https://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Tohoku)) has a temple which is said to be splendid when [azaleas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Azalea) are in full bloom.

What is the good season to see this?

If not full bloom, at least from what month to what month are they usually blooming?

Wikipedia just says that azaleas bloom in spring, their flowers often lasting several weeks. [Sendai climate](https://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Sendai#Climate) is quite unique among Japanese cities.

Comment: *Sendai is considerably colder than most other Japanese cities.* No, it isn't.

Comment: @fkraiem: I changed the sentence, you must know better than me as you live there. Would you agree with the following sentence from Wikivoyage? "*There are two ways of looking at the weather here. One is the way most Japanese people seem to look at it: it's not too cold in the winter and not too hot in the summer, compared to other Japanese cities to the south. Others find it chilly year round.*"

Answer (score 3):

"The good season"? That's going to be spring.  They don't flower in other seasons.
I know you're likely hoping for an accurate week or three, but much like the cherry blossoms, it differs from city to city, and from year to year (a warmer year = earlier than normal).

However, you can probably use the estimates of the cherry blossoms to predict the azaleas.  [The Bloom of Cherry Blossoms](https://www.jnto.go.jp/sakura/eng/city.php?CI=8) for example, does a prediction, and is currently forecasting blooms to start on April 3, with full bloom about a week later on April 9.

So based on that, April seems like a good time.

Scrolling down, you can see the past ten years of history for the blooms, and it's fairly consistent that the second week of April will either see full or first blooms.

Obviously, azaleas aren't cherries, but searching elsewhere seems to indicate they regularly bloom together, so it's a fair bet.

Bonus answer: [a photo taken in Sendai in May, of an azalea in full bloom](https://www.flickr.com/photos/arditpg/5756821760/). However we can't know if it's in a garden, was at a florist or what, but it's an indication that bloom may go for a while.

Comment: Yes, cherry trees and plum trees have rather reliable blooming information, so I was hoping azaleas forecasts would be available as well. They last longer than cherries, it seems.